A Controller cannot read html file from templates
I have a Spring Boot project in which I have the following structure:
the project structure
The controller class is not returning form.html.
This is my Controller class:
`@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String form(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("userEntity", new UserEntity());
        return "form";    
    }`


This is a part from form.html:
`<form method="post" th:object="${userEntity}" th:action="@{/submitItem}">
          <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" th:field="*{firstName}">
          <p style="color: red" th:errors="*{firstName}"> </p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" th:field="*{lastName}">
          <p style="color: red" th:errors="*{lastName}"> </p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" th:field="*{profileName}">
          <p style="color: red" th:errors="*{profileName}"> </p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" th:field="*{email}">
          <p style="color: red" th:errors="*{email}"> </p>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>`

this is UserEntity.java:

`@Entity
@Table(name = "users")

@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
      
    @NotBlank(message = "First name cannot be blank")
    @Size(min = 2, message = "First name is too short")
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Last name cannot be blank")
    @Size(min = 2, message = "First name is too short")
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username cannot be blank")
    @NonNull
    @Username(message = "Cannot contain special or uppercase characters.")
    @Size(min = 7, message = "Username is too short")
    @Column(name = "profile_name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String profileName;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @Past(message = "Date of birth must be in the past")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Email(message = "Invalid email")
    @NotBlank(message = "email cannot be blank")
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "password cannot be blank")
    @NonNull
    private String password;`

application.properties:
`server.port=8080

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/Prostogram
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop 
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=1234
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html`

Application.java:
`@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }, scanBasePackages={
    "com.example.something", "com.example.application"})
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 

    }
}`

The request I make:
localhost:8080/users/form/
because I need the form.html to be shown
it gives me:
whitelabel error page
when I make a request:
localhost:8080/
it gives me index.html from the static folder
